# written list data to file with newlines

Tags: erlang

I'm reading a text file in to a list, the contents are:

```
blah
blah
blah
```

Now I'm trying to write the list data in to a file so it looks the same as above, what I was using is:

```
filewrite(File,L) ->
    {ok, S} = file:open(File, write),
    lists:foreach( fun(X) -> io:format(S, "~n",[X]) end, L),
    file:close(S).
```

but this prints everything on 1 line, with brackets and speech marks...

Comment: I have no clue about Erlang, but it might be a problem caused by Windows' line policy, "/r/n" and not only "/n", try to open the file with another editor or in Ubuntu. Must say, I'm only trying a long shot.

Comment: What does the list look like? Could you give an example of a list and its output?

Comment: Your code contains an error: the list in the last argument to the call to `io:format` should contain **exactly** the right number of arguments for the format string. In your case the `~n` requires no arguments so the last argument should be the empty list `[]`. Often the compiler will catch this and it is always caught at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
filewrite(File, []) ->
    ok;
filewrite(File, List) ->
    file:write_file(File, lists:foldl(fun(E, A) ->
        A ++ "\n" ++ E
    end, hd(List), tl(List))).
```